# Gatling active user drops to zero for longer run

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, stress-testing

When i am trying to run the gatling script for longer duration say, more than an hour, i see the active user is dropped to zero after few minutes into the test. I have tried `atOnceUser(nbUser)`, `constantUsersPerSec(rate) during(duration)` but the end result looks like the one below.

[image]

I am not able to figure out what is causing this issue because if the active user dropped to zero, then logically there should not be any request going in. Also one additional info: All my request gets completed in 200 ms mark.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some error either with colected statistics or with report. During execution gatling generates `simulation.log` file which contains data about each user and request. You can check there if new users were not generated after some time, but if requests were executed i would bet that only reports are wrong. It uses highcharts (external library) to generate reports and in few versions there were issues with plots fe. some series were not printed. Maybe try to use older (or newer) version of gatling-highcharts.